# Receiving APNS notification but cant display on device in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, apple-push-notifications

Hello everyone,
              I am trying how to implement `pushnotification`.For this i have read apple official document for push notification and also read raywenderlich blog and i understand the flow of pushnotication very well. I have created `development and production certificate,profile` and its working fine and push was successfully sent and receiving in -

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo{
      *** display message in uialertview******
}
```

but my problem is how can i display push in my device like other push notification on top up side for both when my application is foreground and background too.

currently i am trying for `IOS 7.0 and XCode Version 5.1.1` (5B1008)

Thanks In advance.

Comment: push notification not receive when your app is foreground plz check notification when your app in background. you receive device token for push ?

Comment: Yes i received device token and sent push successfully and i got push message in my didReceiveRemoteNotification....but my problem is how to dispaly this message like other app pushnotification.

Comment: i think check in your device setting-> notification center your app is appear their or not ?.

Comment: yes it is appear with all pushnotification options..

Comment: hi any idea http://stackoverflow.com/q/24990435/510814

Answer (score 4):

First of all check via these methods in App Delegate that if your registered successfully to APNS.

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken
{
}
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)error
{
}
```

then in

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
{
NSDictionary *Notification = userInfo;

    NSString *title = [(NSDictionary*)[(NSDictionary*)[Notification valueForKey:@"aps"] valueForKey:@"alert"] valueForKey:@"title"];
    NSString *body = [(NSDictionary*)[(NSDictionary*)[Notification valueForKey:@"aps"] valueForKey:@"alert"] valueForKey:@"body"];
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationState] == UIApplicationStateActive)
    {
}


else if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationState] == UIApplicationStateInactive || [[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationState] == UIApplicationStateBackground)
{
UILocalNotification *localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
        localNotification.userInfo = userInfo;
        localNotification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
        localNotification.alertBody = body;
        localNotification.fireDate = [NSDate date];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
 }

}
```

If your application is in active state show UIAlertView. if its not you need to show a UILocalNotification.

Answer (score 1):

When you are in `Background mode` then push notification will display as per your application notification settings from notification centre. you dont have to display ios will do that.

when you are in `Foreground mode` then notification will receive and `-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo` method will be called. so using this method you get userinfo. just NSLog userinfo dictionary and then you can create customview with label at top and animate it like ios default banner.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: thanks for replaying +1....yes you are right that in background state IOS will automatically handle but is it possible to create customview such as like banner??

Comment: checkout this 2 libraries [link 1](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/crtoast) and [link 2](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/cmnavbarnotificationview)

Comment: @user3140414 library helps you?

Comment: @user3140414 If you satisfied with answer then you can upvote and/or accept it as an answer.Happy Coding.

Comment: @RoxeN Rmani :: for upvoting needed 15 because i am new on stack overflow so dont have permission :( :(

Answer (score 0):

As per Apple's note push/local notification will be display only when app is background mode. If notification is arrive at the time of app is on foreground/active then you need to manually manage it because iOS won't show a notification banner/alert That's default design.

I just put my logic here for manage notification when app in foreground mode:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo 
{    
    // check the application state for app is active or not. 
    if (application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateActive)
    {
       // Nothing to do if applicationState is Inactive, the iOS already displayed an alert view.
       UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Receive a Remote Notification" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Your App name received this notification while it was running:\n%@",[[userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"] objectForKey:@"alert"]]delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
       [alertView show];
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to receive notification in top of the device like banner style then follow these steps.

1. First, you need to launch the 'Settings' app on your iOS device.
2. Once you're in, choose 'Notifications' from the list of options.
3. Here's a list of every app that supports push notifications. The ones at the top have been granted permission by you
4. You can also set the alert style. **You can choose the banners that conveniently appear at the top of the screen**, or full-on pop-ups that force you to take action before they go away. Or you can just choose 'None'.

For more detail check this [link](http://www.pocketgamer.co.uk/r/iPhone/iOS+6/feature.asp?c=47769).

Hope you will get something from my answer.

Comment: thnks for replaying and give you +1. i follow your step and by default Alert Style is banner in My Notifications menu and it is not possible to display my alert view such like banner style.

Comment: as i know notification will display in banner style when app is in background or not active. and you will get notification in alert style  when app is running in foreground state i am not saying i am damn true  you can research in google about it @user3140414