# APNS notification received but not display

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad, apple-push-notifications

I am trying to implement pushnotification. I get pushed message when app is running state.

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {

NSLog(@"\n\n\n apns==%@\n\n\n",userInfo);


}
```

my problem is when I pushed message when app is not running means badge count only show on the app icon. It will not display the alert like close and view buttons. Even I cont predict

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

    NSLog(@"\n\n\n\apns==%@\n\n\n\n",launchOptions);
}
```

I checked also in settings --> Notifications --> myApp --> choose badges, sounds, alerts

I'm using config below:

Mac os 10.9

xcode 5.0.2

ios 7.0

Please advice me.

I want this message.

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You have to setting Alert view for Displaying  your coming Push notification Message like:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
{
    if (application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateActive)   
    {
        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"App Notification" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"] objectForKey:@"alert"]]delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alertView show];
    }
}
```

---

when your application in Background Mode or close then that manager by apple you can't handle it. you have to setting Alert prompt from device-->setting. And you badge Display because that automatically functionality of you badge count it's an integer value so that setting automatically. just set push notification setting from device--> setting-->Notification Center--->find your App--->select it and that display like:

[image]

**UPDATE:**

Your push Notificaton Payload JSON formate should look like this:

```
{
    "aps": {
         "badge": 10,
         "alert": "Hello world!",
         "sound": "cat.caf"
    }
}
```

Comment: it will work when my app is open state. But my problem is app closed state. only badge value shown in the app icon. but not display message. I think it will come under appdelegate application  didfinishlaunchingwithoptions method.

Comment: when your application in Background Mode or close then that manager by apple you can't handel it. you have to setting Alert prompt from device-->setting. And you badge Display because that automatically functionality of you badge count it's an integer value so that setting automatically. just set push notificaiton setting from device--> setting

Comment: settings --> Notifications --> myApp --> choose badges, sounds, alerts

Comment: I choose Alerts in the alert style. Even I cont get alert message

Comment: when app is open means I get message from apns.
 apns=={
    Msg = "You have just pushed data via APNS";
    badge = 1;
    sound = default;
}
. problem in closed state. Is it any changes required in infoplist

Comment: check my update answer your are using json with msj key might be that is an issue from back end side that formate should as i metion in my answer check thes

Comment: consider this is your first push message. now your badge count as 1. you close the alert msg. Now how can you increment the badge count value.

Comment: that manage by backend teamnot from ios development. thathave to create logic with each User database having its own badge count and for clear that need to run webservices when app Open.

Comment: If app is closed means when ever app is open. Is it possible to open every notification one by one.Is there any way to save notification if notification close action pressed. where to handle this close button action.

Answer (score 1):

When app is closed and it gets a push notification then the push notification is available in the `launchOptions` parameter in `-didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`

You can access it this way:

```
//when app is closed initially but launched after tapping on the push notification 
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    if (launchOptions) { //launchOptions is not nil
        NSDictionary *userInfo = [launchOptions valueForKey:@"UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey"];

        if (userInfo) { //userInfo is not nil
            NSLog(@"%@",userInfo);
        }
    }
    return YES;
}

//when app is in background or active
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
{
    NSLog(@"%@",userInfo);
}
```

---

<sub>ref: my answer on a similar question: [Push Notification -didFinishLaunchingWithOptions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20795979/2857130)</sub>

Comment: Here is my problem. I cont get alert message. (//when app is closed initially but launched after tapping on the push notification )

Comment: when app is open means I get message from apns. aps =     {
        Msg = "You have just pushed data via APNS";
        badge = 1;
        sound = default;
    }; . Problem is in closed state. Is it any changes required in infoplist.

Comment: @Senthilkumar : so... you want the alert to show in the app after the user taps on the push notification?

Comment: No. Even I cant get home screen alert message with close and view button, I want this one first.

Comment: @Senthilkumar : what all have you passed in `-registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:`

Comment: [[UIApplication sharedApplication]
  registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
  (UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert |
   UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge |
   UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound)];

Answer (score 0):

I just got same problem and I have found issues and fixed. 
You need to check value of alert on

```
{
    "aps": {
         "badge": 1,
         "alert": "your value!",
         "sound": "default"
    }
}
```

I think `"your value"` is null when you call `json_encode`.